# Cannot connect to SQL Server RDS from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I deployed a .NET application to Elastic Beanstalk and would like to connect to My SQL Server Web Edition instance in Amazon. From my office PC this is not a problem, since I authorized my IP address in a security group and attached that to the SQL Server instance.

However from the Beanstalk environment I get this error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
The connection string is the same as the one I use in the office test environment.

I tried adding the security group of my Beanstalk environment, but that didn't help. See picture.

[Configured Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWz3c.jpg)

Does anyone have suggestion on what to do to succesfully connect?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Did you add the private or public IP address? I am not sure about Beanstalk but I know that in my In Bound rules for RDS I have to specify the private IP address (not the public one) of the EC2 instance that requires access. However for other services I need to add rules using the public IP address. I am not using DB Security Groups but EC2 Security Groups for access control to RDS by the way.

Comment: Using IP addresses instead of security groups is a horrible way to do this, and wouldn't work with beanstalk. You need to add a rule to your RDS security group to allow access from any servers in the security group your beanstalk servers are using.

Comment: I did both: adding the internal IP and adding the security group in which the Elastic Beanstalk application is running. Both set to 'Authorize', but still unable to connect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.